# Rails replace f.date_select by html5 input type date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-4

hi together I want to replace this:

```
  <%= raw t("settings.pause", :pause_starts_on => f.date_select(:pause_starts_on, {:include_blank => true, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :start_year => Time.now.year}, {:class => "form-control"}).force_encoding("UTF-8"),
      :pause_ends_on => f.date_select(:pause_ends_on, {:include_blank => true, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :start_year => Time.now.year}, {:class => "form-control"}).force_encoding("UTF-8"))%>
```

by standard html5 input type.

I tried this:

```
<input type="date" name="pause_starts_on" class="form-control" />
```

But I got this error:

```
When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
```

Whats going wrong?

Comment: Could you post your full view code please? Or at least the relevant section if it's very large.

Comment: I've added the full original code. It is based on 6 inputs start(day,month, year) and end (day,month,year) I want to replace it with modern HTML5 date picker, one for start and one for end